# How do I set x = x + 1 for y amount of times without a for or do loop?

Tags: vb.net

In Vb I am trying to set variable x = x + 10 for y amounts of time.
What I have now is this:

```
For z As Double = 0 To Y
x = x + 1
Next
```

I want no do or for loops because they take up a lot of time and resources for larger y values.

Comment: That sounds like multiplication to me.

Comment: In your example, if your For/Next block **only** does `x = x + 1`, why don't you just delete the loop and write `x = x + y + 1` ? Though you said `x = x + 10` y amount of time, just write `x = x + ((y + 1) * 10)`. Be consistent in your issue. Are you doing ***something else*** in your loop ? If it's the case, your question **lacks** this critical piece of information. Otherwise, this is just a simple math : why would you go through a loop if you can get x value in a one line multiplication/addition ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for (cue dramatic music) Mathman!

I think you'll find multiplication is the key, something along the lines of

```
x = x + y * 10
```

if you want to add ten each time, or the even simpler

```
x = x + y
```

if you're only adding one.

Although you may have to use `(y + 1)` instead of `y` if your loop truly is `0` through `y` inclusive. It's a little unclear  from the question exactly what you're after.

Comment: You're missing the iteration for z = 0 (...to y) which still add +1 to x in the addition, and +10 in the multiplication.

Comment: @Stephen, added that in. There are at least four different ways you could interpret the question, hopefully I've covered all bases now.